# OO Javascript Calling method from another method of same object

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm having trouble calling a method from within another method of the same object.

Any help on what I may be missing, or what to look for, would be greatly appreciated.

```
var IceCream = function (flavor) {
  this.tub = 100;
  this.flavor = flavor;
};

IceCream.prototype = { 
        scoop : function () {
            this.updateInventory; alert("scooping");
        },
        updateInventory : function () {
            this.tub --;
        alert(this.tub);
        }
};

 var vanilla = new IceCream("vanilla");
 vanilla.scoop();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert this

```
 this.updateInventory;
```

to this

```
 this.updateInventory();
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/dgh403z9/)**</kbd>

Comment: you just 30 seconds fater than me, sigh

Comment: glad to know :P i am the rabbit here :P @KevinSimple

Comment: ah damn, what an easy one! Thanks a lot @Anik